# Можете пожалуйста обьяснить, что означает данный код

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;
using HarmonyLib;
using MelonLoader;

namespace TestMod
{
    // Token: 0x02000003 RID: 3
    public partial class TestMod : MelonMod
    {
        // Token: 0x02000004 RID: 4
        [HarmonyPatch]
        private partial class Patches
        {
            // Token: 0x06000004 RID: 4
            [HarmonyPrefix]
            [HarmonyPatch(typeof(PlatformSteam), "vk", MethodType.Getter)]
            public static bool vkRoom(PlatformSteam __instance, ref socialNetType __result)
            {
                __result = socialNetType.vk;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

как я понимаю этот код должен выбирать сервера от какой платформы подключаются к игре но могли бы вы конкретнее обьяснить что за что отвечает

Comment: Спрашивайте у автора этого кода

Comment: автор этого кода хочет чтоб я сдох поэтому не выйдет

Comment: Этот код устанавливает `__result` значение `socialNetType.vk` и возвращает `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Harmony - это библиотека для Unity, предназначенная для замены или дополнения реализации методов во время исполнения.

В "нормальном" программировании подобная практика считается грубым костылём и порицается, вместо неё рекомендуется использовать такие практики как оставление точек расширения и внедрение зависимостей. Однако, создатели игр редко думают об удобстве мододелов, и у последних зачастую не остаётся альтернатив подобным костылям.

Конкретно этот код подменяет свойство `PlatformSteam.vk` так, чтобы оно всегда возвращало `socialNetType.vk`. Этот патч является крайне странным, поскольку не вполне понятно почему вообще свойство `PlatformSteam.vk` может возвращать что-то ещё.